# does assistant editor in xcode 3.4.3 has an alternative?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, hackintosh

First, I have xcode 3.4.3 installed on my hackintosh(10.6.5). When I started using xcode , I follow apple's steps from "Your First Mac App" tutorial. When I walked through creating actions for controls, it ask me to use the assistant editor to create connections between control and logic code, but I can't find anything called assistant editor is this because I am using xcode 3.4.3?

Could somebody please tell me some alternatives.

Comment: Assistant editor was introduced in xcode 4 it doesn't exist in xcode 3.4.3 please see the release notes for xcode 4 http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//edit: The assistant editor seems only present at xcode 4 and higher, so the tutorial you are using is newer than you current xcode version. Thanks @popeye for the hint.

The alternative is simply add the connections by yourself. You have to add the outlets in the interface-file (h-file) and the implemenations in the implementation-file (m-file).

There is a good tutorial video fromon how to achieve this:
[Xcode 3 Recipes - Connecting an Outlet](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/#recipes/XcodeRecipes/Connecting_an_Outlet/OutletConnection.html)

**Old Post:**
The mentioned "assistant editor" is just a neat way to connect your outlets with your code. It connects the GUI with the code. For example if you have a button on your screen and you want to register a touch event on that than you can simply use the assistent editor to do that.

It is on the upper right corner of xcode. See the screenshot:
[image]

It shows you a split view with the code on one side and the Storyboard on the other. If you have that view open you can simply hold the control-key and drag a connection from the gui element to the code.

From the apple website: Assistant (): presents a separate editor pane with content logically related to that in the standard editor pane. Use the split controls in the Assistant pane to split the pane. Use View > Assistant Layout to set your preferred assistant pane and split configuration.
[Apple iOS Developer Library - xCode Basics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-general/AbouttheEditorArea/AbouttheEditorArea.html)

Comment: This is not correct, this is not xcode 3.4.3 this is the new interface introduced in xcode 4.

Comment: +1 for updating your answer to indicate it was xcode 4 it was introduced in.

Comment: @Popeye  indeed! it's'not  xcode 3.4.3 does that. what about 3.4.3?

Comment: @haohaochao "indeed! it's'not xcode 3.4.3 does that" OK confirms what I said. But this doesn't make sense "what about 3.4.3?". What do you mean?

Comment: @hao haochao: I updated my answer. Maybe the video can help you.

Comment: @palme, the link you give is very useful for me. thank you two,really!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be out of luck. I do not remember having an assistant editor in XCode 3, not like the version in XCode 4 anyway. Apple tends to keep it docs relevant to the newest release. The link provided by @palme is only relevant for XCode 4.

You might have be resigned to opening multiple windows to compare header and implementation files. In XCode 3, you will have to get used to mutiple windows at times, even seperate applciations (i.e. Interface Builder is completely seperate application from XCode 3).